# How to exclude [select * from table where column values start with a letter]?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**This is an example of my data:**

```
column1
0001OL
0002OL
0003OL
M001OL
A002OL
CDAWOL
```

How can not select values where it starts with a letter?

Do I need an `if statement` and use functions such as `Left(columns1, 1)` and check if it is a letter or there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: Letter - according to what language? Column collation?

Comment: Do you simply want the rows where column1 is starting with a digit?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, that's another way of saying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`LIKE` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '[a-z]%'
```

This will return only the records where the `column` field do starts with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` with a character class:

```
where column1 like '[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

Comment: When I use not like and your query above - I still get values returned such as this: `M877510OL`. Rubens answer worked to solve this.

Comment: @NotLikeSQL . . . The `not like` was there for about 5 seconds before I changed it.

Comment: What I meant was - this `'[^a-zA-Z]%'` did not do any good for some reason, whereas this `'[a-z]%'` got me the desired output.

Comment: @NotLikeSQL . . . Your question is for rows that do NOT start with a letter ("How can not select values where it starts with a letter?").  That is what this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the first character is a digit:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Left(column1, 1) between '0' and '9'
```